# Proving completeness of the real number line.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the real number line $\Bbb{R}$ is complete. I know that every cauchy sequence in $R$ has a bounded monotone subsequence. Hence, if the subsequence has a limit $l$, the original sequence is also convergent to $l$. However I am having difficulty in proving two things:

1. that there exists such an $l$.
2. that $l$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$, and not outside of it. For example, the bounded cauchy sequence $3,3.14,3.141,\dots $ does not converge in $\Bbb{Q}$

How should I go about proving this? Thanks!

Comment: which topology are you using? under the normal topology $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}$ is a metric space with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. These are the only facts provided.

Comment: By the Heine-Borel theorem a set in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is bounded and closed. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded.

Comment: @DimaMcGreen Completeness is a property of metric spaces (in this instance anyway). Complete metric spaces can be homeomorphic to non-complete metric spaces and so it is not a topological invariant. $\mathbb{R}$ is complete but $(0,1)$ is not.

Comment: @hudialala Are you allowed to use the Least Upper Bound property of the reals? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Least_upper_bound_property

Comment: Oh sh**. Im really sorry, I tend to confuse the words complete and compact in English. Embarassing... :(

Comment: @DanielRust- Is the least upper bound property an axiom of real numbers?

Comment: But as far as 1. goes: any bounded sequence has at least one limit point (Bolzano-Weierstrass)

Comment: For some people it is, for others it is an emergent property that needs to be proved.

Comment: According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_upper_bound_property), one might be making a circular argument if one was to prove cauchy completeness using the lub property of real numbers.

Comment: @DimaMcGreen- I think Bolzano-Weierstrass proves every bounded sequence has a monotone bounded subsequence, which converges to the lub **provided** such an lub exists. It does not prove the existence of such an lub.

Comment: It does depend on which axioms you use. If you're given the Cauchy sequence definition of the real numbers, then you have to prove LUB. If you're given the synthetic definition, then LUB is an axiom from which 'cauchy completeness' follows as a theorem, together with the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @hudialala According to wikipedia, Bolzano-Weierstrass says that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence and "convergent" implies the existence of a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the [Least Upper Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers) property of the real numbers. I'm not sure if you are allowed to use this, but for some definitions it is built right in to the real numbers.

You've already shown that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a bounded monotone subsequence, so let's assume wlog that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded increasing. We want to show that the sequence converges to $\sup\{a_n\}$. By hypothesis, let $l=\sup\{a_n\}$ which exists by the least upper bound property and the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. There exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_N>l-\epsilon$ as, if not, $l-\epsilon$ would bound $\{a_n\}$ from above which contradicts the definition of $l$. Now, $\{a_n\}$ is increasing and so for all $n>N$, we get $$|l-a_n|=l-a_n\leq l-a_N<\epsilon,$$ and so by definition of limit we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \{a_n\}$ exists and is equal to $l=\sup_n\{a_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I like to answer your second question as your first doubt should be clear by Daniel Rust's answer. $Q$ is not complete. So a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ may not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, as you have given an example. Such type of sequences will converge at some point of $\mathbb{R}$, a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score -1):

first **completeness of R**

$$let\ \left \{ x_{n} \right \}\ be\ a\ cauchy\ sequence\ in\ R\\
\\
\\
i.e\ \ \ \forall \epsilon >0\ \exists N\ >0\ \ni \ \ d(x_{n}\,\ x_{m})=|x_{n}-x_{m}|<\epsilon \ \ \ ,n,m>N\\
\\
\\
so\ {\left \{ x_{n} \right \}}\ convergent\ sequence\ of\ numbers\\
\\
\\
\\
\therefore \ \ \ \therefore x_{n}\ \rightarrow x\ \ \in \ \ R\\
\\
\\
\ \ \ \ Hence\ R\ \ is\ a\ complete\ \ metric\ space$$

second  **incompleteness of Q**

$$let\ Q\ set\ of\ all\ rational\ number\ with\ metric\ define\ by\ \\
\\
\\
d(r_{1}\ ,\ r_{2})=|r_{1}-r_{2}|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ , r_{1}\ \ ,r_{2}\ \ \ \in \ Q \\$$
\
\
$$if\ \ x_{n}\ =\left [ 1+\frac{1}{n} \right ]^n\ \ \ \ \ ,\
 n=1\ ,2,..........\\
\\
\\
then\ \ \left \{ x_{n} \right \}\ \ \ is\ \ a\ cauchy\ \ sequence\
 \ \ \ and\ \ x_{n}\ \rightarrow \ e\ \ \ \ \\$$

\$$
but\ \ \ e\ \ \ \nless \ Q\ \ \ \\$$
\
$$\\Hence\ \ \ Q\ \ \ is\ \ incomplete\ \ metric\ \ \ space\\$$